# Testing an iphone web app on windows

Tags: iphone

When developing web apps for the iphone on a mac you can test your app in either Iphoney or the apple supplied simulator; bot of them are excellent for the task but are only available for macs. So I have to ask, are windows alternative for these iphone simulators?

So far I could only [find this one.](http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662)

Comment: Unbelievable. I think Apple should provide us this kind of tools/simulators. Our goal is to develop good apps for THEIR devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a roundup of mobile sims see here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing

Specifically http://www.testiphone.com/ (but I'm not sure of the quality of the results from this).

I've also got a Firefox plugin, but its only really good for size.

Your other option, all-be-it naughty and long winded is to run OSX - either on a hackintosh or there are blogs showing how to run it in VMWare player.

Comment: Thanks a heap, I believe that link pretty much answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [iBBDemo](http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662). I relatively new at it, but so far it's the robustest free windows iPhone emulator I had tried yet.

There is also [MobiOne](http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/) which looks like the most promising of all.This is a windows only emulator with lots of features (setup file is 130mb). However even if its not clear right now, I believe at some point you would require to buy a license for it (considering its made by the same company that makes [myEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/), but I might be wrong).Any way its worth the download time

Hope this helps

Comment: Yep iBBDemo is what I settled with at the end, it's basically a png wrapping a safari window but it does the trick if you just want to get a feel of the UI with the right proportions.

Thanks!